# Coming off SSL certificate

Tags: redirect, ssl, https

My website was once popular and held names in an email database. I had an SSL certificate.

Alas, no more. The site is a wasteland, no one goes there anymore yet I don't have it in me to shut it off. I want to leave it up.

The websites SSL certificate runs out soon. I was going to just adjust the redirects that I have from http://example.com to https://example.com and switch them around.

But a friend told me that doing that will fire up a warning to everyone who does still visit (A few folk still go there). You know those browser warnings about how a site cannot be trusted.

Is there a way to come off using SSL certificates without visitors seeing the site cannot be trusted warning? I want to revert to an http website.

Comment: It all depends on what your users have bookmarked and whether you've been using [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Comment: You can not redirect an HTTPS request in that scenario, because it well never even come that far – when the browser “blocks” the request because of an invalid/expired SSL certificate, you do not even get to the point where you could do a redirect on HTTP level.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. Put another way is their a "correct" way to revert to http without a user being shown the "Warning, unrecognized site"? @Bruno how would I find that out?